Jenkins Agent Connection Issues with Windows Server 2022/2016: Stuck During Final Connection Step
I have Windows Server 2022 and Windows Server 2016, which we are using as Jenkins agents (slaves). Recently, these agents have started experiencing issues when attempting to connect to the Jenkins master. The connection process gets stuck almost at the end, and here’s a log from one of these connection attempts:

As you can see, the process gets stuck at this step, and even after waiting for some time, the connection does not complete.
After restarting the Windows server, the agent can connect successfully. However, if we restart the Jenkins master and then try to reconnect the same agent (which was recently restarted), it gets stuck again.
The successful connection process should look like this:

Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can we resolve it?
Thanks
